# How to create a list of lists using unique values in a dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below where one ticket has multiple item associated with it.

```
| ticket_no | items |
|-----------|-------|
| 1         | Item1 |
| 1         | Item2 |
| 2         | Item3 |
| 2         | Item4 |
| 3         | Item5 |
| 3         | Item6 |
| 3         | Item7 |
| 3         | Item8 |
```

Need output as below.

```
[[Item1, Item2],[Item3, Item4], [Item5, Item6, Item7, Item8]]
```

I have tried below code. It works, but it is terribly slow.

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
item_list = []
for ticket_no in data['ticket_no'].unique():
    temp_data = list(data[data['ticket_no'] == ticket_no]['items'])
    if len(temp_data) == 1:
        pass
    else:
        item_list.append(temp_data)
```

Is there a faster way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `list` to `Series` and then convert it to `list`s - output is nested lists:

```
item_list = data.groupby('ticket_no')['items'].apply(list).tolist()
print (item_list)
[['Item1', 'Item2'], ['Item3', 'Item4'], ['Item5', 'Item6', 'Item7', 'Item8']]
```

Comment: Thank you. That works. Also, if the nested lists have only one item, I need to discard it. Can do it by looping over it but is there any other way?

Comment: @SachinPrabhu - Simpliest is filter before solution by `df = df[df['ticket_no'].duplicated(keep=False)]`

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.